# Add stacking modules to powered on GSM7252PS

Tags: stacking, netgear-prosafe

I've looked all over and can not find a for sure answer to this. Can you insert stacking modules into a Netgear GSM7252PS while the switch is still powered on? This switch is located in a production environment so downtime is hard to come by.

Comment: Nothing in the hardware installation manual says anything about allowing this. You should probably err on the side of caution. The alternative is to ask the manufacturer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netgear's official answer is to power off the device before adding HSM cards.  From [GSM7228PS/GSM7252PS Product Information | Answer | NETGEAR Support](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/14140)

> **What are the two I/O modules for?**
>
> There are three modules that are available for these module slots:
> AX741, AX742, AX743 and AX744. AX741 is for 10G XFP. Netgear offers
> both multi-mode and single mode XFP, AXM751 and AXM752 respectively.
> AX742 is the stacking adaptor that comes with short Infiniband cable
> to provide up to 12 Gigabit of bandwidth in one direction. And AX743
> is for the newer 10 Gigabit SFP+ module. Netgear also offers AXM761
> and AXM762 SFP+ for multi-mode and single mode fiber. And AX744
> provides CX4 10-GbE interface.  The I/O modules are not hot pluggable.
> You need to power off the switch, insert or move the modules, then
> power on the switch.

Comment: I just had to come in before hours and turn the devices off. Everything is working great now!

Answer (score 1):

I did it several time in the past, without trouble, running image 8.0.3.34.

Of course there's always a risk that something goes wrong, so you have to assess the impact of a (unlikely) failure versus the impact of a planned downtime.